# Display enrollment by date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create a result set that looks something like this:

```
8/16/19, Enrollment_count

8/17/19, Enrollment_count

8/18/19, Enrollment_count
```

Up to Present day.

The code I have successfully extracts the total enrollment for any given day by adjusting the `@asofdate`.

Is there any easy way to get a COUNT of each day up to present-day formatted like above?

```
DECLARE @asofdate SMALLDATETIME

SET @asofdate = '08/16/2019'


SELECT SE.STU_MASTER_ID
      ,

MAX(SE.ST_ENROLL_TYPE_ID) AS ST_ENROLL_TYPE_ID


FROM STU_ENROLL  SE
WHERE
    @asofdate BETWEEN SE.START_DATE AND ISNULL(SE.DROP_DATE,GETDATE())

GROUP BY SE.STU_MASTER_ID
```

**UPDATE:** Here is something I worked on that actually works.. However, it displays each in it's own resultset. Is there a way to make it display as one resultset?

```
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @startdate SMALLDATETIME
SET @startdate = '08/16/2019'

WHILE @startdate <= GETDATE()
BEGIN 
    SET @count = (
                   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SE.STU_MASTER_ID) AS ENROLLED
                   FROM STU_ENROLL  SE        
                   WHERE
                      @startdate BETWEEN SE.START_DATE AND ISNULL(SE.DROP_DATE,GETDATE())
                      AND SE.ST_ENROLL_TYPE_ID = 1              
                 )
           SELECT @startdate AS 'DATE'
                 ,@count AS ENROLLED
    SET @startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, @startdate);
END
```

Comment: in your output do you want the START_DATE and the Enrollment_count?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will provide the output you requested (if the date in the output is StartDate)

```
DECLARE @asofdate SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @asofdate_end SMALLDATETIME

SET @asofdate= '08/16/2019'
SET @asofdate_end= '09/16/2019'


;With EnrollDates( EnrollDte) as
(
Select @asofdate as EnrollDte
    union all
Select Dateadd(day, 1, EnrollDte)
    from EnrollDates
    where EnrollDte <= @asofdate_end
)



SELECT 
       --columns you requested
       Ed.EnrollDte As EnrollDate, 
       COUNT(*) AS Enrollment_Count


FROM STU_ENROLL  SE
Inner join EnrollDates ed
          On Ed.EnrollDte BETWEEN SE.START_DATE AND ISNULL(SE.DROP_DATE,GETDATE())
Group by Ed.EnrollDte
```

Comment: So the code I sent spits out enrollment AS OF a certain date. I want to be able to see what total enrollment was AS OF each date of a certain month. So let's say if you put the setasdate to 8/16/19 and the total enrollment count was 42000, and you change it to 8/17/19 and total enrollment was 41500. two columns, the AsOfDate, Total Enrollment Count, for each day of a specified range. Does that make sense?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer according to your requirement. I’ve used a CTE in this instance. It’s really handy when it comes to recursive use cases. Might be worthwhile reading up on it for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, first you'll want all the dates in your output range in a table, then we can simply left join the student enrolment data and aggregate:

```
declare @From date, @To date
set @From = '2019-8-16'
set @To = '2019-9-1'

-- Create list of "as of" dates
declare @Days table ([Day] date)
while (@From <= @To)
begin
  insert into @Days values (@From)
  set @From = dateadd(day, 1, @From)
end

-- Return student enrolment counts for each day
select d.[Day] as [AS_OF]
  ,count(*) as Enrollment_Count
from @Days d
  left join STU_ENROLL SE
    on SE.START_DATE <= d.[Day] AND (SE.DROP_DATE > d.[Day] or SE.DROP_DATE is null)
group by d.[Day]  
order by d.[Day]
```